# Map tables using fluent api in asp.net MVC5 EF6?

Tags: claims-based-identity, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I am trying to add profile/Membership information into my MVC5 application and adding configuration mappings.

I get the following error message:

> my.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no
>   key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>
> my.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key
>   defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>
> IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is
>   based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
>
> IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based
>   on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Discriminator { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }     
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationUserConfiguration());           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

Calling `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)` did not solve the issue for me.

The behavior of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework seems to be different in VS2013-Preview,  VS2013-RC, and VS2013-RTM. I'm using the RTM version.

After inheriting from IdentityUser I had to recreate all other primary keys in the model to make it work:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}


public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
    }
```

(See [Configuring/Mapping Properties and Types with the Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591617#1.2))

I guess work on AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework is ongoing and this will be fixed (?)

Comment: I've had to do exactly the same thing to get by this issue. I thought that EF would pick out the entity IDs automatically?

Comment: This resolved it all for me! Many thanks - should be marked as answered :)

Comment: I have had a similar problem and tried this solution and thought it fixed the problem but I am getting few extra tables in the database such as IdentityUsers, and I also still have AspNetUsers table. What did i do wrong?

Comment: @LaurenceNyein place base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder) as last call in methode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913447/user-in-entity-type-mvc5-ef6 fixed it for me

Answer (score 19):

Call `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)` after configuration added.

Comment: if this doesnt work..try calling it before the configurationaded

Comment: It would seem `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` must be called if `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` is used, `OnModelCreating` overridden, and I am not manually configuring `IdentityUserLogin`, `IdentityUserRole` and `IdentityUserClaim` with attributes or the fluent API.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps around `OnModelCreating` method and test after each one to be aware of taking effect:

1. Make sure you have one `Context` to prevent of their rule conflicts.
2. Call `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` inside the mentioned
   method (first of all)
3. Add the followings plus previews step in the method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
```