# User in Entity type MVC5 EF6

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have created a class in MVC5, where I want a primary owner of the content and then I want to have some editors for the content:

```
public class Content
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public IdentityUser Owner { get; set; }
    public ICollection<IdentityUser> Editors { get; set; }
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

In the database context I have the following code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Content>()
        .HasOptional(c => c.Editors)
        .WithRequired()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Content>()
        .HasRequired(c => c.Owner)
        .WithOptional()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete();
}
```

I would expect Microsoft to have implemented the `IdentityUser` object in such a way, that it can be used in other entity types, so I am probably doing something wrong, because when I try to make a controller for the Content entity type, I get the following error:

```
EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined
EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined
EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no key defined
EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no key defined
```

I have also tried to add the following code to the `ApplicationDbContext` as described in this question [Map tables using fluent api in asp.net MVC5 EF6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474662/map-tables-using-fluent-api-in-asp-net-mvc5-ef6):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
}
```

I must be doing something wrong. Please tell me how I can handle users in my Content EntityType.

Comment: Your `Content` class appears to be missing the foreign key ID.

Comment: When working with EntityFramework, you don't need a foreign key ID field. You just set a property to the associated type and EF does the rest (like storing a foreign key ID in the database).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The following method, `OnModelCreating`, will create a working context. Not sure if it is the mapping you want though.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Content>()
        .HasMany(c => c.Editors)
        .WithOptional()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Content>()
        .HasRequired(c => c.Owner)
        .WithOptional()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
}
```

Comment: My mistake, I have two contexts, application context and content context, and I had my key mappings for the IdentityUser in the application context. Now it works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Is it a bug? i have another context and no relate to ASP.NET Identity context that project created. so why i have a the last 3 lines?

Comment: Error to generate model entity:Se han detectado uno o varios errores de validación durante la generación del modelo:

Usuario_ObPais_Source: : La multiplicidad no es válida en el rol (Role) 'Usuario_ObPais_Source' de la relación 'Usuario_ObPais'. Como las propiedades de Dependent Role no son las propiedades de clave, el límite superior de la multiplicidad de Dependent Role debe ser '*'.

Comment: This worked fine until you go into details. The PROBLEM with this approach is, that if you want to add multiple user logins for the same user(facebook & google), this will not work because the primary key is set to the UserId in IdentityUserLogin. You cannot add multiple external logins with the same primary key.

Answer (score 106):

I had the same problem and I found that I had not called

```
 base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```

in my DbModel

Comment: This shoudl be the accepted the answer, a lot of people remove the base class implementation with DbContext but it is vital when inheriting from IdentityDbContext

Comment: I got the same error and before using the accepted answer, I read your answer and realized I had removed that line of code. That solved the problem and am sure this is the answer most of the time someone runs into this issue.