# How do I create primary key for class that inherits IdentityUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have created an MVC 5 site using Identity 2.0.  I am using integer for primary key.

When I try to create a Model with an association to ApplicationUser I get the following error:

> EntityType 'ApplicationUserRole' has no key defined.

What do I need to do to fix this error?

IdentityModels.cs

```
public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }
public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { }
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<int, ApplicationUserRole>, IRole<int>
{
  public string Description { get; set; }

  public ApplicationRole() : base() { }
  public ApplicationRole(string name) : this()
  {
    this.Name = name;
  }

  public ApplicationRole(string name, string description) : this(name)
  {
    this.Description = description;
  }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>, IUser<int>
{
  public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
  {
    var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    return userIdentity;
  }

  public string FullName { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Employee.cs

```
public class Employee
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public string Title { get; set; }

  public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to override the OnModelCreating method to define the primary keys:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserLogin>().HasKey<int>(l => l.UserId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().HasKey<int>(r => r.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
}
```

Here's a similar thread: [User in Entity type MVC5 EF6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913447/user-in-entity-type-mvc5-ef6)