# ASP.NET MVC5 EF6 Relation with ApplicationUser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity-2

```
[ForeignKey("Creator")]
public string CreatorID {get;set;}
public virtual ApplicationUser Creator {get;set;}
```

I have a model which I want to save the creator and modifier.
But there are errors during migration

```
TSRDTEST.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

TSRDTEST.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.

IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
```

I'm using built in login/logout/register template,with database column prefixs "AspNet", is there any way to fix that error without modify entire project project and preserve the columns with prefix AspNet, Thanks

Comment: That almost reads like a haiku. Can you please re-phrase the question to make it more readable?

Comment: Updated, could you please read again, thanks.

Comment: Do you have two DbContext ? for example `ApplicationContext` (by default exist when you create an ASP.NET MVC project) and another DbContext  which you have created.

Comment: public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    ,    public class DefaultConnection : DbContext two, yes!

Comment: Have a look on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19916771/809357

Comment: I've tried that but ruins the project for identity and extra table added with 'Identity' prefix, is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I didnt understand what you want to do. But the mapping between entities should be look like this.

```
    public string CreatorID {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("CreatorID ")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser Creator {get;set;}
```