# ASP.NET Web API Identity property from another DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have `StoreUser` identity in my ASP.NET Web API project and `StoreDbContext`
Where I have `Product` model and `DbSet`

this is my `Product`

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CodeName { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    public int SoldCount { get; set; }
    public string SellerId { get; set; }
    public virtual StoreUser Seller { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ProductImage> Images { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ProductText> Texts { get; set; }
}
```

this is my `StoreDbContext`

```
public class StoreDbContext: DbContext
{
    public StoreDbContext() : base("MyCoupon")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new StoreDbInitialier());
    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductText> ProductTexts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductImage> Images { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CategoryText> CategoryTexts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Language> Languages { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my `StoreUser`class

```
public class StoreUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; } = new List<Product>();
}
```

so user can have products

but when I want to add them 
with

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Seller")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(Product product)
    {
        var userId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<StoreUserManager>();

        var user = userManager.FindById(userId);
        product.Seller = user;
        _db.Products.Add(product);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return Ok(product);
    }
```

I am getting error

[image: error]

Comment: Write out / copy paste the error. don't you picture.

Comment: Paste the text of the error message in your post, please.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call, on your `StoreDbContext` class

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer, but I am getting same error

Comment: @ArenHovsepyan check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913447/user-in-entity-type-mvc5-ef6