# No keys when trying to connect ApplicationUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm using VS 2015 and the latest version of ASP.NET Identity 2.2.1 in MVC 5 project.

I have this simple model:

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser SomeUser { get; set; }
}
```

Basically, 1-to-1 relationship with `ApplicationUser`. And a usual context;

```
public class Db : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

I now go and do `Enable-Migrations` for this context. Everything works fine. I then go and do `Add-Migration SomeInitialMigration` and get the following:

```
WebApplication18.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
WebApplication18.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
```

If I first start the app (and the database tables are created), this error occurs when I type `Enable-Migrations`.

I've been reading on how to solve this, implemented [this SO answer solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19562411/4214184), however, now not only it doesn't solve the problem, but when I hit 'Register' for a new user, or 'Login', I get:

```
ApplicationUser_Logins_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'ApplicationUser_Logins_Target' in relationship 'ApplicationUser_Logins'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.
```

I've also tried only adding `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` in `ApplicationDbContext` as suggested by [this SO snswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913447/user-in-entity-type-mvc5-ef6) but nothing happened as well.

I'm not sure what to do, pretty much tried all SO solutions to similar problems. Maybe something changed with Identity source code and no longer work.

Basically, what I'm trying to accomplish is this: I Want to connect so an ApplicationUser has many students. And I've tried testing this so I add a simple relationship to `Student` for a start, nothing fancy. So knowing this, if there's any alternative approach that's worth taking to connect a registered users to custom models via one-to-many or one-to-one, please let me know.

Comment: your Db inherits from DbContext instead of IdentityDbContext